# BUG?? ImageView causing background image to stretch

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to write an xml representing the following GUI:

```
--------------------
|            <text>|
|            <text>|
|                  |
|<pic>             | 
--------------------
```

in the background I want to have an image....
I wrote the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/layout_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:background="@drawable/image1"
          >
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget48"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/transparent"
>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
    </TextView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

with the following xml the background image looks fine, but the ImageView is not located where I want it to be...
after adding the following:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

to the ImageView  the background image is stretched and looks ugly....

How do I set the image to the bottom-left without causing the background to get stretched???

THANKS!

---

First of all thanks for trying to help....
Tried your last suggestion

> try to change both the relative layout and linear to : android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

still no success... 
I made the code even easier - removed the outer layout,

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget48"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/single_detail"
>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingTop="50px"
    android:paddingRight="25px"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#0000FF"
    >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingRight="25px"
    android:textColor="#0000FF"
    >
    </TextView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

still same problem as seen in the images....  other ideas??

I am hopeless......    :)

HELP!!!! PLEASE!!!!

Answer (score 0):

if you want the image to be the backgroud of the layout just put it in `android:background=`in the relative layout

but if you want to use the imageView you can change `android:scaleType=` in the image view so it won't stretch

Comment: tried your suggestion but this doesn't fix the problem. to be more specific, the ImageView is not the one who get streched - the problem is with the background image which streches the moment I add the alignParent attributes to the ImageView, so scaling the ImageView does not seem like the answer here. more suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: i don't get it , please clarify :
do you want to exclude the image view from the layout so the background won't stretch?

Comment: as I "draw" it in my post, I want to have a background image behind my textviews and image view, and to be able to align the imageview to the bottom-left of containing view. if I don't set the alignparent parameters on the imageview, the background image + textviews + imageview looks fine - but the imageview is not aligned.  when adding the alignment, i can see the imageview aligned to the right place with the right size, however causing the background image to stretch and become ugly - this is my problem.... hope now it is a bit clearer...

Comment: if the space covered by the textviews + imageview is bigger than the background then you need a new one

Comment: it is not bigger............  the background just get stretched for no reason.....

Comment: you can add images in the question .. could you please attach a screenshot

Comment: I can't add images... new users restrications... reputation..... can I email it to you?

Comment: try to change both the relative layout and linear to :
 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: see my new answer... still no luck... :(

Comment: i just noticed that the image in the first picture is in the bottom left corner , where do you want to put it?

Comment: exactly there but above the background image and not causing it to get streched (as you can notice in the images attached...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to the problem:

**GOOD:**
[image: Good]

**BAD:**
[image: Bad]

Comment: the first picture represents how it should look like (using a workaround of PaddingTop....)  ,  2nd image shows how the background get stretched after adding the 2 lines in xml...